# Create new set of subsets out of set of subsets (python)

Tags: python, algorithm

How would you achieve the following (in Python):

```
List 1: qw,wq
```

Now add e before the first element and behind each element of each subset

```
List 2: eqw, qew, qwe, ewq, weq, wqe
```

Needless to say this should be constructed in a general way, so that List 1 could be of any proportion.

I was thinking of a recursion, but yet my function uses many if/elses and is not too nice.

Comment: Sets are unordered, hence the question. I have posted an answer with lists.

Comment: @AchmedDurangi though this isn't an answer to the question you're asking, you can also look at `itertootls.permutations` for a similar solution. It doesn't preserve order of elements like your answer requires, but it seems like a relevant function if you're performing operations of this type

Comment: "choose your liking" - sets and lists are completely different things, unless you specify which it is you want, anyone who answers has a 50% chance of addressing a question you didn't want to ask.

Comment: I want to solve the problem. set/lists/dict/hashtables/trees/graphs it really does not matter. What I do not want to use is any ready-made python module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could work:

```
a = ['qw', 'wq', 'test']

def merge (tgt, letter):
    for i, _ in enumerate (tgt):
        yield tgt [:i] + letter + tgt [i:]
    yield tgt + letter

b = [x for tgt in a for x in merge (tgt, 'e') ]
print (b)
```

It prints

```
['eqw', 'qew', 'qwe', 'ewq', 'weq', 'wqe', 'etest', 'teest', 'teest', 'teset', 'teste']
```

I hope this is the expected result.

---

Or taking into consideration Steven's input:

```
def merge (tgt, letter):
    for i in range (len (tgt) + 1):
        yield tgt [:i] + letter + tgt [i:]
```

Comment: do not use enumerate where (x)range would suffice ;)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski True enough. I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Using the the generator in a slightly cleaner fashion

```
elements = ['qw', 'wq']

def silly_op(lst, char):
    for e in lst:
        for i in range(len(e) + 1):
            yield e[:i] + char + e[i:]

print(list(silly_op(elements, 'e')))
```

Prints

```
['eqw', 'qew', 'qwe', 'ewq', 'weq', 'wqe']
```

No recursion, no if, just 2 nested loops + generator.

Of course if you want to get the results as a list, you can write

```
def silly_op(lst, char):
    rv = []

    for e in lst:
        for i in range(len(e) + 1):
            rv.append(e[:i] + char + e[i:])

    return rv
```

---

Or if the question is about permutations, as suggested by @AdamSmith,

```
print(list(''.join(i) for i in itertools.permutations('wq' + 'e')))
```

prints

```
['wqe', 'weq', 'qwe', 'qew', 'ewq', 'eqw']
```

Comment: Why not post your own solution instead of gold-plating mine?

Comment: I really don't want to use a generator. Also a nested loop would yield an order of magnitude of n^2, nothing to be proud of in particular. Also, why is your function name called silly_op?

Comment: To answer the criticism here:

1. indeed, no need to use a generator.
2. my code has the same amount of loops as the previous answer
3. there are not n^2 loops, there are nm loops, you cannot do this any faster as the produced list contains n*m elements.